# Redirect the output of one command to more than one command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, io-redirection

I know that using a pipe I can redirect the output of a command to another command:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

Also when I use something like:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
```

the second pipe make that `cmd3` to take the output of `cmd2`. My question is: is it possible to make `cmd3` to take the output of `cmd1`?

Comment: Use 'tee' command. See [this question][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tee`:

```
cmd1 | tee >(cmd2) >(cmd3)
```

or `pee`:

```
cmd1 | pee "cmd2" "cmd3"
```

`tee` should be installed by default in all Unix like systems, while `pee` can be found in `moreutils` package.

Comment: Great solution. Note that `tee` - unlike `pee` - still sends `cmd1`'s output to stdout as well. Caveat: With the `tee` + process substitution (`>(…))` approach, any stdout output generated by `cmd2` and `cmd3`, if any, will be sequenced unpredictably (which one comes first is non-deterministic, and they may even interleave). By contrast, `pee` executes commands and thus produces output in the order in which the commands were given - the only caveat there is that if an earlier command hangs, you won't see output from later ones. Neither `tee` nor `pee` are limited to just two targets.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why this happens, but `pee` sometimes "fails": `seq 100000 | pee 'head -n1' 'tail -n1'`. Probably has to do with how head and tail works.. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `tee` and named pipes:

```
 $ fifo=/tmp/1to3
 $ mkfifo $fifo
 $ cmd1 | tee $fifo | cmd2 & cmd3 <$fifo
```

Comment: For fifo newbies like me: don't forget to delete the fifo (named pipe) afterwards; `rm "$fifo"` in this example. Note that output from `cmd2` and `cmd3`, if any, will be unpredictably interleaved. To suppress the housekeeping info related to the background execution (`&`), enclose the entire pipeline in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

IF **guaranteed order of execution** of `cmd2` and `cmd3` and/or **guaranteed order of their output** (if any) are a concern, using process substitution (`>(...)`) or named pipes (FIFOs) is NOT an option.
Instead:

- Use the `pee` utility as demonstrated in [Radu Radeanu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19912060/45375), if installing it is an option (and it's available for your platform).
- Otherwise, use a temporary *file* as follows:

`cmd1 | { f=$(mktemp) && cat >$f; cmd2 <$f; cmd3 <$f; rm $f; }`

<sup>(On OSX, use `mktemp -t tmp` instead of just `mktemp`; `mktemp -t XXXX` would work on both platforms).</sup>

---